# composition of the functions

Tags: smlnj

I need to write some function NTimesComposition(f:(int * int -> int), n:int) which receives some function **f** and integer **n** and after doing composition of **f**, **n times**, like this f(x,(f(x,f(x,y)))) <- (here for example n = 3) I began to write it on smlnj, but it seems more complicated than I thought thanks in advance for any idea:

```
NTimesComposition(f:(int * int -> int), n:int)
    if n = 1 then fn(x,y) => f(x, y ) else NTimesComposition...//here I'm stuck, must be recurstion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got it for n = 1 and you most likely just forgot to pass the `(x, y)` in the recursive call for n > 1. Obviously here it needs to be something of the form `fn (x,y) => f (x, ...)` where the `...` part is where your recursive calls is going to be.

If you had forgot the `(x,y)` in the recursive part making it `fn (x,y) => NTimesComposition (f, n-1)` then you would end up building a chain of anonymous functions as "long" as your argument `n` describes. That would result in a different type of your `NTimesComposition` function depending on what `n` you supply which is not valid due to the way SML's type system works (Hindley-Milner).

The following two functions will do the job for you

```
fun foo (f, 1) = (fn xy => f xy)
  | foo (f, n) = (fn (x,y) => f(x, foo (f, n-1) (x,y)))
```

and

```
fun baz (f, 1) xy = f xy
  | baz (f, n) (x,y) = f(x, foo (f, n-1) (x,y))
```

where the first resembles your code the most using the anonymous function.